# Is there an equivalent of Array#each_slice() in Ruby 1.8.5?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

I'm using ruby 1.8.5, and the `each_slice()` method for an array is not working.

My code is something like:

```
array.each_slice(3) do |name,age,sex|   .....   end
```

Is there any other way to implement the same functionality in my older version of ruby.

Comment: @the Tin Man: What was wrong with the ruby-1.8 tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bake your own:

```
module Enumerable
  def each_slice( n )
    res = []
    self.each do |el|
      res << el
      if res.size == n then
        yield res.dup
        res.clear
      end
    end
    yield res.dup unless res.empty?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This guy

http://tekhne.wordpress.com/2008/02/01/whence-arrayeach_slice/

figured out you can

```
require 'enumerator'
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got 1.8.5, but you can try this

```
0.step(array.size, 3) do |i|
  name, age, sex = array[i], array[i+1], array[i+2]
  ...
end
```

Comment: thank u very much for ur reply.. In The above code, say for eg if the no. of elements is 3, it works fine for one iteration but in the second and third iteration, the name,age,sex returns nil...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but consider using the [backports gem](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/).